# Pouring water problem

Tags: scala, homework, breadth-first-search

I just began to study Scala (coming from Python I had quite a few problems with types) and I want to know if my first code to solve a real problem is nicely done or if there is some points that need to be redone.

The problem I had to solve is for an homework but my code is already working, I just want to know if it be more *Scalish*:

> **Problem description**
>
> We have \$k\$ containers, where \$3 ≤ k ≤ 10\$. Container \$i\$ has a certain integer capacity \$c_i > 0\$ (of liters of water). Initially, container \$i\$ contains an integer amount \$a_i ≥ 0\$ of water. We are allowed to perform only one kind of operations: Take one container \$i\$, and pour its contents into a different container \$j\$. Pouring stops when either \$i\$ becomes empty, or \$j\$ becomes full (so after the operation either \$a_i = 0\$ or \$a_j = c_j\$).
>
> Is it possible to achieve a certain target configuration, and, if so, how?
>
> For instance, let's assume we have three containers with capacities \$10L\$, \$7L\$, and \$4L\$. Initially, the \$7L\$ and \$4L\$ container are full, while the \$10L\$ container is empty. The question is if we can achieve that the \$4L\$ container contains exactly \$2L\$ of water.
>
> With our notation, we have \$k = 3\$, \$c_1 = 10\$, \$c_2 = 7\$, \$c_3 = 4\$, \$a_1 = 0\$, \$a_2 = 7\$, and \$a_3 = 4\$. The question is: Is it possible to reach \$a_3 = 2\$?
>
> The answer is yes, and here is a possible sequence of moves (displayed in reverse order):
>
> ```
> 2 7 2
>
> 2 5 4
>
> 6 5 0
>
> 6 1 4
>
> 10 1 0
>
> 4 7 0
>
> 0 7 4
> ```

I solved the problem using BFS on a graph I'm building at every step.

```
import collection.mutable.HashSet
import collection.mutable.Queue
import collection.mutable.ArraySeq
import scala.io.Source
import java.io.File

case class Container(capacity: Int, filled: Int) {

    // overload + and - methods
    def +(toAdd: Int) = {
        assert (filled + toAdd <= capacity, { println("Too much water in container")})
        new Container(capacity, filled + toAdd)
    }

    def -(toSub: Int) = { 
        assert (filled - toSub >= 0, { println("Not enough water in container")})
        new Container(capacity, filled - toSub)
    }

    // how much can we pour into an other container ?
    def howMuchToPour(other: Container) = 
        math.min(filled, other.capacity - other.filled)

    // just print the filling level when printing a Container
    override def toString(): String = filled.toString;
}

case class State(containers : ArraySeq[Container]) {
    var parent:State = _

    // returns all the ancesters of a State
    def ancesters() : List[State] = 
        if (Option(parent) != None) parent :: parent.ancesters
        else                        List[State]()

    // returns a new State with i-th container poured into j-th container
    // no check if it's possible or not
    def pour(i: Int, j: Int, q: Int) = {
        val new_containers = containers.slice(0, containers.length) // make a copy
        new_containers(i) = containers(i) - q
        new_containers(j) = containers(j) + q
        val ns = State(new_containers)
        ns.parent = this
        ns
    }

    override def toString(): String = containers map{_ toString} mkString "\t"

    def next_states() = 
        for { i <- (0 until containers.length);
              j <- (0 until containers.length)
              q = containers(i) howMuchToPour containers(j)
              if (i !=j) && q > 0 }
            yield pour(i, j, q)
}

object Pouring {
    def _bfs(start: State, condition: (State) => Boolean) : List[State]  = {
        val q = Queue[State]()
        val seen =  HashSet[State]()
        q    += start    
        seen += start

        while (q.length > 0) {
            val s = q.dequeue()

            if (condition(s)) 
                return s :: s.ancesters

            s.next_states().foreach(ns => {
                if (!seen.contains(ns)) {
                    q    += ns
                    seen += ns
                }
            })
        }
        List[State]()
    }

    def solve(problem:Seq[Array[Int]]) {        
        val state = State(problem(1).zip(problem(2)).map(x => Container(x._1, x._2)))

        val cond_funcs = for { (filled, index) <- problem(3).zipWithIndex
                                                            .filter(x => x._1 != 0) } 
                            yield (x:State) => x.containers(index).filled == filled

        _bfs(state, (x) => cond_funcs.forall(_(x)))
            .reverse
            .foreach(s => println(s))
    }

    def main (args: Array[String]) = {
        solve(Array(Array(3), Array(10, 7, 4), Array(0, 7, 4), Array(0, 0, 2)))
    }
}
```

The points that I think can be improved but don't know how:

- The parent member of `State` is a `var`.  Would it be possible to instantiate an object `State` with a parent member? I tried but I couldn't since the first State has no parent.
- This could probably be done using iterators, but I don't know much about that yet.

Comment: `new Container(capacity, filled + toAdd)` -> no `new` needed for case classes.

Comment: Trying to learn from the code that's presented here. What's the purpose of the following line val state = State(problem(1).zip(problem(2)).map(x => Container(x._1, x._2))). I understand the zip but I am confused about the map and how it applies over the State class?

Comment: nevermind..I read the statement wrong. The zip and the corresponding map is passed as an argument in the State. I missed the params enclosing the operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm is more important than code style. I haven't given it much thought, but it seems that this might be solvable with dynamical programming, or some more efficient method than brute force search.  Also, the brute force search algorithm will run for ever if there is no solution.  I implemented below a slightly modified version of your algorithm, where I keep track of visited states.  It increases performance and it does terminate.

As mentioned in another answer, it's better to use `List` or `Stream` rather than arrays.  Your loops over array indices are very un-functional.

You did use immutable data structures, except `ArraySeq`.

Instead of your main `while`-loop, I am using a recursive function.  It's always possible to get rid of loops (for/while) using recursive functions.  It's not wrong at all to use a `while`-loop; it's just more "functional" to use a recursive function.  Even more "functional" than using recursive functions is to use the collection operations such as `list.map`, `list.foreach`, `list.foldLeft`, `list.filter`, etc.

Here is my solution (using the same brute force search algorithm, but keeping track of visited states):

```
object PourSolution extends App {

  case class Container(id: String, capacity: Int)
  type State = Map[Container, Int]
  type Move = (Container, Container) // (from, to)

  // Only moves where source is non-empty and destination is non-full.
  def possibleMoves(state: State): List[Move] = {
    val containers = state.keys.toList
    for {
      s <- containers
      t <- containers
      if (s != t && state(s) != 0 && state(t) != t.capacity)
    } yield (s, t)
  }

  def applyMove(state: State, move: Move): State = {
    val from = move._1
    val to = move._2
    val remainingCapacity = to.capacity - state(to)
    val transfer = math.min(state(from), remainingCapacity)
    if (transfer == 0) state
    else state ++ List(from -> (state(from) - transfer), to -> (state(to) + transfer))
  }

  // Performs a breadth-first-search.
  // Warning: the moves in the returned list are in reversed order.
  def solve(initState: State, targetState: State): Option[List[Move]] = {
    require(!doesMatch(initState))
    require(targetState.nonEmpty)

    lazy val targetStateAsSet = targetState.toSet
    def doesMatch(state: State): Boolean = (state.toSet & targetStateAsSet) == targetStateAsSet

    @tailrec
    def loop(states: List[(State, List[Move])], statesNextDepth: List[(State, List[Move])], visitedStates: Set[State]): Option[List[Move]] =
      (states, statesNextDepth) match {
        case (Nil, Nil) => None
        case (Nil, statesNextDepth) => loop(statesNextDepth, Nil, visitedStates)
        case ((state, moves) :: tail, statesNextDepth) =>
          val nextMoves = possibleMoves(state)
          val nextStates: List[(State, List[Move])] = nextMoves.map(move => (applyMove(state, move), move :: moves))
          val newNextStates = nextStates.filter(p => !visitedStates.contains(p._1))
          val exactSolution = newNextStates.find { case ((s, _)) => doesMatch(s) }
          if (exactSolution.isDefined)
            exactSolution.map(_._2)
          else
            loop(tail, newNextStates ::: statesNextDepth, visitedStates ++ newNextStates.map(_._1))
      }
    loop(List((initState, Nil)), Nil, Set(initState))
  }

  val c0 = Container("c0", 10)
  val c1 = Container("c1", 7)
  val c2 = Container("c2", 4)
  val initialState = Map(c0 -> 0, c1 -> 7, c2 -> 4)
  val targetState = Map(c2 -> 2)

  val solution = solve(initialState, targetState)

  solution match {
    case None => println("No solution")
    case Some(reversedMoves) =>
      val moves = reversedMoves.reverse
      moves.foreach(println)
      val movesWithState = moves.scanLeft(initialState)(applyMove(_, _))
      movesWithState.foreach(println)
  }
}
```

Note that I use one list of the states at the current depth and another list for the states at the next depth.  I did this because otherwise one would need a FIFO queue (all the states of the current depth are at the head of the queue), but I'm not sure that there is an efficient immutable implementation of such a queue.

Answer (score 2):

It seems pretty reasonable, actually. I'm confused by the `ArraySeq`. Also, I'd rewrite this:

```
   if (Option(parent) != None) parent :: parent.ancesters
    else                        List[State]()
```

As

```
   Option(parent).map(parent => parent :: parent.ancesters).getOrElse(List[State]())
```

That is, *if* used `parent` as you did. I'd make it an `Option` instead, and initialize it at creation.

I'm not sure `Iterator` would help you here, but `Stream` might. I just don't think it is a particular good fit for BFS, but it might just be ignorance on my part.

Comment: OK. I looked up for Option and I think this is actually what I wanted.

I've put :
`case class State(containers : ArraySeq[Container], parent: Option[State] = None) {`

`def ancesters() : List[State] = this.parent match {  
        case Some(parent) => parent :: parent.ancesters
        case None         => List[State]()
    }`

Now my first state is created without "parent" parameter and when I create a new State when pouring:

`State(new_containers, Option(this))`

I think this is good right ?

Thank you very much for the advice :)

Comment: I had also to redefine hashCode and equals in order not take account of member "parent".

Comment: @PatrickBrowne Instead of modifying `hashCode` and `equals`, you could have `parent` on a second parameter list. IIRC, only stuff in the first parameter list is taken into account on the auto-generated methods.

Comment: I don't see how I can put parent in a second parameter list. As I understood, in Scala when you want to add another constructor, it has to call the first constructor and this is why you have to put the most generic constructor first. In my case, the most generic constructor is the one with parent so I can't put it as the second one. Am I wrong ?

By the way, I used ArraySeq because one ArraySeq is considered equal with another if they have the same content. This is not true for Array.

Comment: @PatrickBrowne `case class State(containers : ArraySeq[Container])(parent: Option[State] = None)`

Comment: @PatrickBrowne And, as for `ArraySeq`, the thing is that this is an unusual collection. If you don't want to mutate it, `Vector` would be more indicated. If you do want to mutate it, one of the `Buffer` classes is usually more appropriate.

Comment: OK, it works with a second parameter list and the ArrayBuffer but I somewhat find the syntax val a = State(elements)(parent) a bit weird :) Anyway, thank you very much for your time and answers !